# How to assert io errors in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, error-handling, rust

There are plenty of tutorials showing how to write unit tests in Rust. I've read dozen and all of them focuses on asserting values in case of success. Situation doesn't seem so straight forward in case of an `error`. Errors do not implement `PartialEq` trait by default so you can't use `assert_eq!` macro. Also, some functions may return multiple variants of error depending on what kind of issue occurred (ex. `io::Error` which may be of different kind.) I could just check if error occurred or not but it doesn't seem enough.

Example below.

```rust
fn parse_data(input: i32) -> Result<i32, io::Error> {
    match input {
        0 => Ok(0),
        _ => Err(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData, "unexpected number"))
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_parsing_wrong_data() {
    let result = parse_data(1);
    assert!(result.is_err());
    let got = result.unwrap_err();
    let want = io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData, "unexpected number");

    // compilation error here: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `std::io::Error`
    assert_eq!(want, got);
}
```

I assume this is not idiomatic approach, since it's not compiling. Hence the question - what is a proper and idiomatic approach in similar situation?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

TL;DR: `Error` should implement [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html)

[`Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) only implements [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#impl-PartialEq%3CResult%3CT%2C%20E%3E%3E) when `T` and `E` also implement [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html), but [`io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html) doesn't. [alex](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/34192#issuecomment-225149676) confirm that cause `io::Error` takes an extra error that implements [`dyn Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), allowing the user to add extra information lead std to not implement `PartialEq`.

---

I see a lot of answer and comment that seem a lot of peoples use `io::Error` to create their own error. This is NOT a good practice, `io::Error` should be used only if you deal yourself with `io`. There is the [Error Handling Project Group](https://github.com/rust-lang/project-error-handling) if you want to learn and share your view about error in Rust.

For now there is some common crate in Rust to make your own error (feel free to add crate):

- [snafu](https://crates.io/crates/snafu) (my favorite)
- [thiserror](https://crates.io/crates/thiserror)
- [anyhow](https://crates.io/crates/anyhow)
- [quick-error](https://crates.io/crates/quick-error)

I don't totally agree but here a good [guide](https://www.lpalmieri.com/posts/error-handling-rust/) about Error in Rust.

---

Anyway, the solution that you probably want in your case is just to compare the [`ErrorKind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/enum.ErrorKind.html) value. As `ErrorKind` implements `PartialEq` this will compile with [`assert_eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.assert_eq.html)

```rust
use std::io;

fn parse_data(input: i32) -> Result<i32, io::Error> {
    match input {
        0 => Ok(0),
        x => Err(io::Error::new(
            io::ErrorKind::InvalidData,
            format!("unexpected number {}", x),
        )),
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_parsing_wrong_data() {
    let result = parse_data(1).map_err(|e| e.kind());
    let expected = Err(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData);
    assert_eq!(expected, result);
}
```

Comment: I have a function returning `Result<String, ParseError>`, I added `#[derive(PartialEq)]` to `ParseError` and it worked!

Comment: I found this post very helpful, although I have just a small nit that the expected and result should be swapped in the assertion [i.e. assert_eq!(result, expected);]. I believe this varies between different programming languages!

Comment: @BenSmith Rust specifically does *not* ascribe meaning to the first or second argument of `assert_eq!`. That's why the failure text refers to them as `left` and `right`.

Comment: Touché! After double checking, it was the IntelliJ IDE returning Expected and Actual in failing tests when run via the “play button”. Indeed one would see left and right when executing the standard (intended) cargo run.

Comment: If your error type doesn't have a `.kind()`, ie. if using `thiserror` crate, use @scoopr's answer.

Comment: @SamMyers not really, the question is about how to assert error in Rust, the general answer is error should implement PartialEq, the `.kind()` part of my answer is just specific to the OP, sccopr answer is unclear for me.

Answer (score 31):

I solved it with this

```rust
assert!(matches!(result, Err(crate::Error::InvalidType(t)) if t == "foobar"));
```

This solution doesn't require `PartialEq` for the `Error`, but still allows me to compare with the variant contents.

If you don't care about the contents of the variant, then its just

```rust
assert!(matches!(result, Err(crate::Error::InvalidType(_))));
```

Comment: This is more powerful then the answers that just check the type, as it also contains the content. Doing that is considered to be an anti-pattern in rust, though, as content (like error strings) can change, and do not allow for compile time verification.

Comment: Well in my case, I actually wanted to test for the content (that the error was from the identifier I expected), which I don't see as anti-pattern at all, I'm not comparing against the `Display` string.
But the pattern match can of course just omit the comparison, if you don't care about the value. I've amended the answer with an example of that.

Comment: any reason to not write `assert!(result, Err(crate::Error::InvalidType("foobar")));` ? I don't understand your answer please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If you mean `assert_eq`, then that requires `PartialEq` Impl, which my enum didn’t trivially have, and as I pointed out, this solution doesn’t require it. Which is elegant in that it wasn’t needed outside the test anyway.

Comment: Thanks, `matches!` is just what I needed. Not all errors (e.g. `TryFromSliceError`) implement `PartialEq`! I don't know why, but not much I could do about it apart from work around it.

Comment: Also, looks like there is `assert_matches` in nightly. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/assert_matches/macro.assert_matches.html

Answer (score 9):

If you use the type `Result`,
there is a built in method [`is_err()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.is_err).

This means you can test with `assert!(my_result.is_err());`.

Comment: the question already contains this advice `assert!(result.is_err());` the question is about how to check the expected error is returned

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had several structs with differents fields, they all implement the `std::error::Error` trait. This worked for me in a cleaner way than making an instance of any struct I needed:

```rust
let result = parse_data(1);
let your_error = result.unwrap_err().downcast_ref::<MyCustomError>();
assert!(your_error.is_some());
```

That downcasts the error to a specific type, in case it's the correct type it's a `Some(_)` value, otherwise, it's `None`. However, I'm a newbie in Rust, it's probably that this is not the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: using io::Error, to make its own error is probably a bad idea, look for something like snafu crate

Comment: Hi! Why It would be a bad idea?

Comment: io::Error, have never been design to be use that way, it should only be use for io error at max. also downcast on error look... bad. If the error is an opaque type, this mean the error should be used as opaque so no downcast, if your error must be usable for user, then it should not be a opaque type so not a dyn Error but an enum of error possibility. I don't fully agree with https://www.lpalmieri.com/posts/error-handling-rust/ but it's mostly a good guide.

Comment: But I use `std::error::Error`. Would it have the same problem?

Comment: well, as I said, if you wrap all your error into opaque type `std::error::Error` you should NOT need to do what you do in your answer. Cause you choice to make error opaque. I recommend you to read the guide I link and pick either snafu or thiserror crate. You may be interested by anyhow crate if you want to keep your error opaque.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I'll check how I could improve my crates!

Answer (score 1):

A macro using [Genaritos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68185731/586229).

```rust
macro_rules! is_error_type {
    ($result:ident,$err_type:ident) => {
        $result.unwrap_err().downcast_ref::<$err_type>().is_some()
    }
}
```

used like this:

```rust
let result = parse_data(1);
assert!(is_error_type(result, MyCustomError));
```

Answer (score 0):

Example from the `assert_matches` documentation:

```rust
#![feature(assert_matches)]

use std::assert_matches::assert_matches;

let a = 1u32.checked_add(2);
let b = 1u32.checked_sub(2);
assert_matches!(a, Some(_));
assert_matches!(b, None);

let c = Ok("abc".to_string());
assert_matches!(c, Ok(x) | Err(x) if x.len() < 100);
```

It's still experimental in nightly (2023).